# How to run multiple versions (via multiple profiles) of Firefox?

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I downloaded three versions of Firefox: 3.6, 3.5 and 3.0 from Mozilla ftp server. Then I created three profiles, e.g:

```
firefox -no-remote -CreateProfile firefox-3.5
```

Then I tried to run it:

```
./firefox -no-remote -P firefox-3.5
```

but it failed with the error:

```
./firefox-bin: symbol lookup error: ./libxul.so: undefined symbol: _Z19js_obj_defineGetterP9JSContextjPi
```

or

```
(firefox-bin:4034): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_insert_internal: assertion `hash_table != NULL' failed
```

Actually it worked in 10.10. I dropped in on Mozilla’s Firefox IRC channel and one dude told me he had never seen this bug before so I suppose that it is Natty issue.

Comment: Try to encapsulate the profile name with quotes. Also see my reply below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get [FoxTester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtester/) extension. It allows to install/launch/uninstall multiple versions of Firefox using multiple profiles, directly from your default Firefox.

Keep in mind that FoxTester is designed for testing multiple Firefox builds and not for managing profiles intended for long term usage. If you uninstall a Firefox build installed by FoxTester, it will remove all traces of it, including the profile.

FoxTester install all FF versions and creates the corresponding profiles in the *foxtester* folder, inside the Firefox profile where FoxTester is installed.

If you want more control over your profiles, then use the [standalone profile manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Profile_Manager) instead. But don't use it to manage FoxTester profiles.

Comment: Either there is no reaction, or in case of Firefox 3.0.9 a tiny blank window of very few pixels is opened. Just like what I had by running profiles via terminal.

My system is quite clean, I installed it about 2 months ago. Maybe it matters that I use Kubuntu (though I don’t think so) and I have Firefox from Mozilla ppa?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I have Kubuntu also. Are you downloading the binaries with the same architecture of your system?

Comment: OK, maybe it matters that I use British English localisation across system but tried to use Firefox with Polish one. Now I could run different versions of Firefox except from version 2.0.20.

First, the file pattern is not detected by FoxTester. Second, it won’t even run when it is compressed to bzip.
I know that there is a problem with running Firefox 2 in newer Ubuntus but FoxTester should handle it.

Comment: FoxTester addon has been removed from the Mozilla Addons website.